# Code don't give any errors or results, It never stop

Tags: python, debugging

*English is not my mother tongue, so there might be some grammatical errors in my question. 
Sorry about that.*
I was using a project called "logparser" to parse my log data. "Logparser" can parse log information to a list of templates. I'm not going to explain details of this project, because it's a big difficulty to understand this project completly, and that's why I call it as a black box. I used it to parse "logfile_1", it worked and I got the templates. When I parsed "logfile_2", errors occured because of some lines in "logfile_2", so I deleted these lines. So "logfile_2" should be parsed theoretically just as same as "logfile_2". But when I run code to parse "logfile_2", my python code neither throwed error nor stopped. I tried to debug code, but it's hard to know accuratly the meaning of code. I don't know what to de next. Should I must understand the logic of code step by step to run code correctly? Or there are some debug methods can help me to solve this?
I'm not sure whether I'm understood. If not, I would like to offer you any information that you need. Thank you!

Comment: Please produce a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: We need to see the code

Comment: I put it into my github. But one of codes is about 400 lines, it may takes you much time. Sorry about that. Here is code.[link](https://github.com/steelshadow39/logparser_test)

Comment: I ran SHISO_benchmark.py first. "Linux_test.log" is logfile which ran correctly. "Linux_attack.log" is logfile which leaded program to run forever. The algorithm file is "logparser_test/SHISO/SHISO.py".